# Loading multiple SpatiaLite layers into a single database

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I have many SpatiaLite layers, each in a separate database. I want to load all these SpatiaLite layers into a single database. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are SpatiaLite layers, they are already in a database. If you meant that they are in different databases (which you did not stated in your original question), you can use the DB Manager plugin, just expand your SpatiaLite connections in the `Tree` and drag & drop the SpatiaLite layers you want to import from each DB to your target DB.

Comment: Sorry that I did not mention in my question. And thanks for your time and response.

Comment: @AhamedFarook No problem. BTW, why would you check the answer as accepted and not upvote it? If you consider the answer useful, you could also consider upvoting it.

Comment: @gcarillo It was upvoted as soon as I checked.